# find and sum repeating repeating dictionary elements

Tags: python-3.x

As a Python n00bie, I've stumbled on an problem proven to be unsolveable using my google-fu...
Threfore I kindly ask for your help.

I have a dataset A:

```
[{'addr': 'domain77504.com', 'cnt': 7},
 {'addr': 'domain48598.com', 'cnt': 6},
 {'addr': 'domain14775.com', 'cnt': 6},
 {'addr': 'domain58638.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {'addr': 'domain62558.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {'addr': 'domain4905.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {'addr': 'domain8352.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {'addr': 'domain71048.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {'addr': 'domain18421.com', 'cnt': 5},
 {... and so on ...}]
```

Containing 50 * number_of_cores elements.
It is a piece of larger data: 10M+ emails over 100k domains. That is why there are domains like 'domain71048.com' :)
The cnt value is the number of occurances in previous step of the search.

What would be the best way to find duplicates in dataset A,
sum those duplicates by their 'cnt' and limit dataset A to 50 most frequent elements ordered by their newly calculated 'cnt' descending ?

Comment: can you sort these sets using some built-in function?
after they are sorted, the rest is rather easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Simply loop over the data, updating the counts, and then use the `.most_common()` method to get the results you want.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for d in data:
    k, v = d['addr'], d['cnt']
    counts[k] += v

relevant = counts.most_common(50)
```

Comment: Such a versatile tool this Counter. I used it before in my code however didnt know it could do that :) Awesome ! thank you !